# Python copy sublists with conditions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, binance

```
list_0 = []
list_1 = []


def sort_data():
    trades = client.get_recent_trades(symbol='BTCUSDT', limit=50)
    for t in trades:
        id_zero = [int(t["id"]), int(t["isBuyerMaker"]), float(t["quoteQty"]).__round__(2)]

        list_0.append(id_zero)

    dup = [x[0] for x in list_0]
    for x in dup:
        if x not in list_1:
            ?


while True:

    sort_data()
```

I am connected to the API from Binance and I want to check recent trades. So far, so good, I can get them with the `client.get_recent_trades`

I have to download 50 trades at one time because otherwise it would be too slow and I would lost most of the trades. I can see it on the specific IDs.

`ID: 560, 565, 576, 587, ...` for example are useless for me, I lose the others.

In every package of data are only a few "fresh" ones. I don't want to append duplicates to my lists, so I tried to check the IDs to filter out duplicates with

```
dup = [x[0] for x in list_0]

Example sublist: [234543234, 1, 4543.45]
```

I don't know how to do the following: Check ID for every entry in `list_0` ( ID is on index 0 in sublist ) and when the ID is not in `list_1`, copy the whole dataset / sublist [ID, isBuyerMaker, quoteQty] to `list_1`.

When it would be a "static" routine, I would know what to do, but here I have a routine with fresh data every second and I don't know how to deal with that. I can't do it with the iteration `[-1]` because it is to slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use that in this case, use the websocket:

```
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.client import Client

client = Client('PUBLIC', 'PRIVATE')

lst = []

def process_message(msg):
    lst.append(msg)
    print (lst)

bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('BNBBTC', process_message)
bm.start()
```

The list `lst` will only contain unique recent trades for your symbol. Write that list in a file and load it in your make orders script.